# How to insert cyrillic simbols in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I've created a table lets say Example. And insert values, as follows:

```
insert into Example (column1)
values ('оарвыларфдл');
```

Then I try to select the data from table and the output is: ??????????

Comment: set the table/column type UTF 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up your character sets somewhere: the table, the connection, the output, or some combination of these is using an incorrect character set - so make sure they all match and use a character set that can represent your characters - UTF-8 is generally the best choice, because it can represent everything.

It is not possible to be more exact than this, because you have not provided any information about which character sets each of those things are using.

Comment: I use Zend Framework, WampServer2.2a-x32.exe, Zend Studio (I set there encoding = utf-8) and HeidiSql to manage MySql tables. I tryed to look in httpd.conf, my.ini and php.ini, but didn't found any encoding settings

Comment: @Andrei: That doesn't bring me closer to figuring out the problem, because it tells me nothing about what you're actually doing. How are you checking the data; are you selecting it from your PHP code, or checking it in HeidiSQL? If you're checking it in HeidiSQL, then either the table wasn't created properly, or the data wasn't sent properly when you inserted it (it was converted to latin1 before being sent). Most likely it's just the table definition that's wrong, but if it's not, there are several places where things can have gone wrong, and I can't know which one is the actual problem.

Comment: ok, I shall be more specific: the cyrillic simbols are displayed wrongly first of all in HeidiSQL. When I am creating a table, I am using following code: create table headers (
id integer(9) not null primary key auto_increment,
date date not null,
en varchar(512) not null,
ro varchar(512) not null,
ru varchar(512) not null);   I introduce the data, like following: insert into headers (ru) values ('оолполпт');    And than I type: select * from headers;     Output is: ????????    The browser displays it exactly the same way, as it is in HeidiSql.

Comment: @Andrei: In that case, it sounds like the table is the problem - you didn't specify a character set in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and the default character set for the database is likely something like latin1, which cannot store Cyrillic. Put `CHARACTER SET utf8` just before the semicolon in your [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) statement to force a UTF-8 table and try again (and then run an [ALTER DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-database.html) command to change your database to use utf8 as default).